# Filter data from arrays

Tags: sql, angular, typescript

What I need is to sort data I get from an API into different arrays but add '0' value where there is no value at 1 type but is at the other type/s. Now is this possible with array.filter since its faster then a bunch of for and if loops ?

So let's say I get following data from SQL to the API:

```
Day        Type  Amount
-----------------------
12.1.2022  1     11
12.1.2022  2     4
13.1.2022  1     5
14.1.2022  2     9
16.1.2022  2     30
```

If I run this code :

```
this.data = result.Data;
let date = [];
const data = { 'dataType1': [], 'dataType2': [], 'dataType3': [], 'dataType4': [] }

/*only writing example for 2 types since for 4 it would be too long but i desire 
answer that works for any amount of types or for 4 types */

this.data.forEach(x => {
  var lastAddress = date[date.length - 1]
  if (x.type == 1) {dataType1.push(x.Amount) }
  if (x.type == 2) {dataType2.push(x.Amount) }}
  lastAddress != x.Day ? date.push(x.Day) : '';
```

The array I get for type1 is `[11,5]`
and for type2 I get `[4,9,30]`.
And for dates i get all the unique dates.

But the data I would like is: `[11,5,0,0]` and `[4,0,9,30]`
The size of array also has to match the size of Day array at the end.
which would be unique dates.. in this case:

`[12.1.2022, 13.1.2022, 14.1.2022, 16.1.2022]`

I have already tried to solve this with some for, if and while loops but it gets way too messy, so I'm looking for an alternative.

Also i have 4 types but for reference i only wrote sample for 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can

1. first get the uniq values
2. loop over the data to create an array of object with
   `{date:string,values:number[]}`

```
  //create a function:

  matrix(data:any[])
  {
    const  uniqTypes=data.reduce((a,b)=>a.indexOf(b.type)>=0?a:
                     [...a,b.type],[])
    const result=[]
    this.data.forEach((x:any)=>{
      let index=result.findIndex(r=>r.date==x.date)
      if (index<0)
      {
        result.push({date:x.date,values:[...uniqTypes].fill(0)})
        index=result.length-1;
      }
      result[index].values[uniqTypes.indexOf(x.type)]=x.amount
    })
    return result
  }

  //and use like
  result=this.matrix(this.data);
```

NOTE: You can create the uniqType outside the function as variable and pass as argument to the function

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ybnpcu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Ok and how would you group the same dates into 1...since if you change the date and theres 2 with the same date you will still have the same amount of rows.... i want those with same in the same array

Comment: Im sorry for my broken english but like if u have data like this :  [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xdevdw?file=src/app/app.component.ts) .... i want the ones the same date incommon to be writen in the same row.. like the one with 2 should now be 100 , 80, 0 and 3 should be 100,0,90

Comment: @Beck, sorry, the stackblitz has not updated with the code in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const type1 = [];
const type2 = [];

data.forEach(item=>{
  if(item.type==1){
   type1.push(item.amount)
   type2.push(0)
  }else{
   type1.push(0)
   type2.push(item.amount)
  }
})
console.log(type1)
console.log(type2)
```

Comment: and what if there is 4 types ? also if there are 2 items in the same date this will result this to write 2 values in the array instead of 1... if you take for example the first 2 rows of the data i wrote this would return 11,0 and 0,2 instead of 11 and 2

Comment: The array has to match the order of date array, so this code is wrong as soon as the types have values at the same date